# Multivalue Bound Textblock DataTrigger not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

So I'm trying to Bind a TextBlock to multiple values on my Viewmodel (Mix of Enums and Strings). I have a DataTrigger that is *supposed* to fire when the text is null  when returned by the Converter. But it doesn't! At first, I thought my Style didn't take hold (hence changed the Background on the Style to show it did). Anyway here is the code

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModelLocator}"
                   Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(params:General.BoldPadding), Mode=OneWay}">

            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GeneralMultiStringDisplayConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="RatesViewModel.Instrument.Currency" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    <Binding Path="RatesViewModel.Instrument.Underlying" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    <Binding Path="RatesViewModel.Instrument.ProductType" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
            <TextBlock.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}"> <!--THIS SHOULD FIRE-->
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="ThisShouldFireOnStart"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Resources>
        </TextBlock>
```

The Converter is as follows:

```
class GeneralMultiStringDisplayConverter:IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var AS = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;    
        if (values[0] != AS )
        {
            int count = values.Count();
            string result = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i)
            {
                try
                {
                    var A = Enum.GetName((values[i].GetType()), values[i]);
                    result = String.Format("{0}{1}.", result, A);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    result = String.Format("{0}{1}.", result, values[i]);
                }
            }
            result = String.Format("{0}{1}", result, values[count - 1]);
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
        //TODO:
    }
}
```

**Debugging Steps that I have taken**

```
    `<Setter Property="Text" Value="ABC"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock, Path=Text}" Value="ABC"> 
<Setter Property="Text" Value="ThisShouldFireOnStart"/>
 </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
                           `
```

1. Added a converter to the Styles DataTrigger Binding. It always gets *""* as a parameter and not null for some reason. Setting the trigger Value to *""* does not work.
2. Added a default Text property in the Style and tried changing the Value based off of that. (See example above)

   I would appreciate some help in getting this to work
   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not override these local bindings with a DataTrigger in a Style.
See [Why doesn’t my WPF Trigger work?](http://jimmangaly.blogspot.de/2009/05/why-doesnt-my-wpf-trigger-work.html)

If you just need to show a string if your bindings are null use `TargetNullValue="MyNullValueString"`

Perhaps you need a `if(value[0] != null)` condition in your converter to identify unset properties. Since i do not have any detail of your RatesViewModel i can not say for sure.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GeneralMultiStringDisplayConverter}" TargetNullValue="ThisIsNull">
    <Binding Path="RatesViewModel.Instrument.Currency" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    <Binding Path="RatesViewModel.Instrument.Underlying" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    <Binding Path="RatesViewModel.Instrument.ProductType" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Null is a valid value for DPs and Dp.Unset is the value is set when there is no value on the Dp. This MSDN  ((https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue(v=vs.110).aspx))  article explains the difference. The link to your blog was helpful and the TargetNullValue thing did the trick. I had to move my Bindings into the style and use this tip!. Marking as correct Thanks!